# Python Filter multiple row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

I am using this query script to get data from api rest.

[Script](https://github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py-samples/blob/master/Query%20Data/cube%20data%20into%20pandas%20dataframe.py)

After doing this, I got the following data:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn22u.jpg)

I am new in python, and I have some difficult to understand how do I select columns:

I tried this following code, but it appears:

```
df1 = df[(df['Meses'] != 'Total') & (df['Orcado x Realizado'] == 'Realizado')]

KeyError: 'Meses'
```

[Data problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK8mv.jpg)

Comment: please print `df['Meses']`

Comment: `pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Meses'`

Comment: Just took a look at how you are creating the `data frame`. The problem is that the `Utils` function you use create a multi-indexed `df` with just one column `Values`. What happens if you do `df['Values']`?

Comment: It appears all the data when I do this

Comment: How can I convert into a "normal" dataframe? If I write to csv, it works properly, but is there a straightforward way to do that?

Comment: KeyError: 'Meses'

Comment: I believe you can do `df.reset_index()` to get a "unflattened" data frame.

Comment: I added a picture showing how it appears the data

Comment: Please add pictures in the question and not as external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reset_index()` will do

```
>>> df.reset_index()["Meses"]
```

The code you're using ([link](https://github.com/cubewise-code/TM1py/blob/master/TM1py/Utils/Utils.py)) is setting multi index and one column though

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(keylist, names=dimension_names)
... 
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns=["Values"])
```

Just reset the index to make it a flat `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to filter a MultiIndex dataframe:

**1. Elevate index to columns and filter by columns**

```
df = df.reset_index()
df1 = df[(df['Meses'] != 'Total') & (df['Orcado x Realizado'] == 'Realizado')]
```

**2. Filter by index directly**

```
df1 = df[(df.index.get_level_values('Meses') != 'Total') &
         (df.index.get_level_values('Orcado x Realizado') == 'Realizado')]
```

Comment: When I create this new df, the "values" column disappears.

Comment: Maybe they've run away?... Seriously, if you want a good response you need to provide some code. And, no, images don't help.

Comment: miss one ) at the end

Comment: It seems that this function get all the data inside the list, into a dataframe, but the only column that was already a dataframe,  disappears